# Can we define XML schema as python class and use that to validate xml inputs?

Tags: python, xml

My payloads are in XML format. I have schema for that. Is there a way, that I can define XML schema as a python class and use that to validate XML inputs?
Currently I use lxml library to parse my schema.

Comment: What is bad about parsing your schema file? Why do you need it to be a class? Maybe I could suggest any other solution but I need to know what you want to achieve by using a class instead of schema file.